# How to stop label from blocking user input inside of input element

Tags: css

In the following simplified example I use absolute positioning to place a label inside of an input element.  I use JavaScript to make the label shrink or grow depending on focus / blur.  This works as expected.

**My question:** If I click the text label it blocks focus on the input element and the label doesn't shrink.  If I click anywhere else inside of the element it works as expected.  I tried `Z-index -1` to place the label behind the input box but that didn't solve the problem.  I also tried `user-select: none` but it still blocked focus on the input element.  Is there a way to stop the label from blocking the input element?

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', labelShrink);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', labelGrow);

function labelShrink() {
    document.querySelector('.inputLabel').style.fontSize = ".75rem";
}

function labelGrow() {
    if (!document.querySelector('.inputField').value) {
        document.querySelector('.inputLabel').style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
    } 
}
```

```css
.inputContainer {
    position: relative;
}

.inputLabel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index = -1; 
    padding: .25rem 0 0 .25rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    user-select: none;
    transition: font-size .25s;
}

.inputField {
    padding: .75rem 0 0 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
  <label class="inputLabel" for="userName">User Name</label>
  <input class="inputField" type="text" name="userName">
</div>
```

Comment: The code works as expected in Google chrome on Ubuntu, it isn't blocking for me when I click in the input

Comment: @Justice That's so weird!  I'm on Windows and Chrome and if I click the word "User Name" it blocks it.  Anywhere else in the input box and it works fine.  Maybe the problem is browser/os specific.

Comment: Yeah, that is super odd, glad I know this now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the label so you can click trough it.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', labelShrink);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', labelGrow);

function labelShrink() {
    document.querySelector('.inputLabel').style.fontSize = ".75rem";
}

function labelGrow() {
    if (!document.querySelector('.inputField').value) {
        document.querySelector('.inputLabel').style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
    } 
}
```

```css
.inputContainer {
    position: relative;
}

.inputLabel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index = -1; 
    padding: .25rem 0 0 .25rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    user-select: none;
    transition: font-size .25s;
    pointer-events: none; // Add this line
}

.inputField {
    padding: .75rem 0 0 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
  <label class="inputLabel" for="userName">User Name</label>
  <input class="inputField" type="text" name="userName">
</div>
```

Comment: SuperDJ that worked on the spot!  If you know why does `pointer-events: none` fix it?

Comment: @DR01D from mozilla: : "The element is never the target of mouse events;"